PySide2/PyQt QScrollArea didn't work with flow layout
I had a problem with implementing flow layout inside scroll area. I'm trying to be able to scroll vertically when the current active window is small enough (like in the reference link), but there is still no luck.
Behavior goal
Here is my current code:
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        # context tab configuration
        self.contextScrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.contextScrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.contextScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.contextLayout = FlowLayout(self.contextScrollArea)
        self.contextScrollArea.setMinimumHeight(40)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.contextScrollArea)

        # image count
        for i in range(30):
            self.add_widget(self.contextLayout)

    def add_widget(self, parent):
        self.contextItem = QtWidgets.QLabel("IMAGE")
        self.contextLayout.addWidget(self.contextItem)


class FlowLayout(QtWidgets.QLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FlowLayout, self).__init__(parent)

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(QtCore.QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))

        self._item_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self._item_list.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self._item_list)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list[index]

        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list.pop(index)

        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.Orientation(0)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self._do_layout(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super(FlowLayout, self).setGeometry(rect)
        self._do_layout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QtCore.QSize()

        for item in self._item_list:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        size += QtCore.QSize(2 * self.contentsMargins().top(), 2 * self.contentsMargins().top())
        return size

    def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        line_height = 0
        spacing = self.spacing()

        for item in self._item_list:
            style = item.widget().style()
            layout_spacing_x = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
            )
            layout_spacing_y = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Vertical
            )
            space_x = spacing + layout_spacing_x
            space_y = spacing + layout_spacing_y
            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            if next_x - space_x > rect.right() and line_height > 0:
                x = rect.x()
                y = y + line_height + space_y
                next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
                line_height = 0

            if not test_only:
                item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = next_x
            line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

        return y + line_height - rect.y()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

I hope someone can explain or show me the solution. Thanks in advance!

The layout must be installed on the widget that is set on the scroll area, not on the scroll area itself. Create a container QWidget, set the layout to it, and then call setWidget().

Thank you! that was quick. I already edit my code with your suggestion and working as expected
